# Abstract Algebra cyclic groups digraph question

Tags: abstract-algebra, cyclic-groups

Find the subgroup of Z_12 generated by the subset { 4 , 6 } . Also draw the digraph of this subgroup ⟨ { 4 , 6 } ⟩ .

I have the subgroup of z_12 generated by {4.6} as < gcd {4,6} > = <2>= {0,2,4,6,8,10}.

I am not sure how to draw the cayley digraph?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What is the question, and what did you try?

Comment: What have you tried? This problem is small enough that you could bash it if you wanted, or use the gcd...

Comment: I have the subgroup of z_12 generated by {4.6} as <2>={0,2,4,6,8,10}. <gcd{4,6}>=<2> I am not sure how to draw the digraph?